# Producing default pdf in dita-ot

Tags: pdf, ant, dita

I have created a plugin and trying to generate my output as a pdf . My build is getting successfully , but my plugin is not running. The output is default pdf. What am I missing ?

this is my build_pdf2w_template/ant file:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="org.dita.pdf2w" default="dita2pdf2w" basedir=".">

    <property name="transtype" location="C:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4"/>


    <target name="dita2pdf2w"  description="build PDF" depends="pdf"/>

        <target name="pdf" description="build PDF">
        <ant antfile="C:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4\plugins\org.dita.pdf2w\build_pdf2w_template.xml">
            <property name="args.input" value="D:\AutoCOM-Demo\AutoCOM.ditamap"/>
            <property name="args.gen.task.lbl" value="YES"/>   
            <property name="args.rellinks" value="nofamily"/>   
            <property name="output.dir" value="C:\"/>
            <property name="transtype" value="pdf"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

</project>
```

Plugin:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<plugin id="org.dita.pdf2w">
    <require plugin="org.dita.pdf2w"/>
    <feature extension="dita.conductor.transtype.check" value="pdf2w"/>
    <feature extension="dita.transtype.print" value="pdf2w"/>

    <feature extension="dita.conductor.target.relative" file="build.xml"/>
</plugin>
```

Integrator:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>




<project name="org.dita.pdf2w">
    <target name="dita2pdf2w.init">
        <property name="customization.dir" location="${dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2w.dir}/cfg"/>
    </target>
    <target name="dita2pdf2w" depends="dita2pdf2w.init , dita2pdf2w"/>
</project>
```

build:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
    <import file="build_pdf2w_template.xml"/>
</project>
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up some things. Could you please add your `plugin.xml` file? If you have just started building your plugin, please throw it away and generate a fresh one using the dita-generator: http://dita-generator.elovirta.com/ This is a better starting point.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to add `integrator.xml` of your plug-in.

Comment: @StefanEike sure sir i am adding my plugin xml. One thing i am not getting in : dita-generator.elovirta.com is that  where is the build/ant file after generation?

Comment: @tmakita i had added.

Comment: Are you surely set "dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2w.dir" property in the command-line? It is not defined in build.xml.

Comment: @tmakita i din't get you exactly. Are you mentioning about the ditamap input dir? yes, I had . Please see the "build_pdf2w_template.xml" . "build_pdf2w_template.xml" is getting imported in "build.xml" file.

Comment: _I am getting this error in cmd:-_
`c:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4>ant -Dargs.input=D:\AutoCOM-Demo\AutoCOM.ditamap -Doutput.dir=C:/ -Dtranstype=pdf
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: c:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
c:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4\build.xml:89: Duplicate target 'dita2pdf.init'

Total time: 0 seconds

c:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4>`

Comment: This is my mistake. "dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2w.dir" property should be set by DITA-OT integration automatically.

Comment: "build.xml:89: Duplicate target 'dita2pdf.init'" message means that there is the serious errors in your plug-in integration. It needs your examination of relevant portion in build.xml.

Comment: Unfortunately we have no information about your new target "dita2pdf2waikato". It will be better to tidy up your question and build.xml  environment again.

Comment: @tmakita i toggled that plugin in the dita ot build.xml and now the error is `BUILD FAILED Target "dita2pdf2w.init" does not exist in the project "DOST". It is used from target "dita2pdf2w". Total time: 0 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin.xml looks good, it references directly the "build.xml" so if you have an "integrator.xml", that is not getting called at all.
In the build.xml the ANT target "dita2pdf2w" has at the end an antcall to itself so that is not good.
Basically your build file should have looked like this:

`<project name="org.dita.pdf2w">
    <target name="dita2pdf2w.init">
        <property location="${dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2w.dir}/cfg" name="customization.dir"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="dita2pdf2w.init, dita2pdf2" name="dita2pdf2w"/>
</project>`

You can also use Jarno Elovirta's PDF plugin generator to generate a startup customization plugin:
http://dita-generator.elovirta.com/

Comment: Thank You Sir , Sir I did a little modification according to latest pattern on my ant file kindly review it if it is good. I am having same problem after modifying it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the @RaduCoravu's suggestion I revised your plug-in related files.

[pdf2w/plugin.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="org.dita.pdf2w">
    <feature extension="dita.conductor.transtype.check" value="pdf2w"/>
    <feature extension="dita.transtype.print" value="pdf2w"/>
    <feature extension="dita.conductor.target.relative" file="integrator.xml"/>
</plugin>
```

[pdf2w/integrator.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <import file="build.xml"/>
</project>
```

[pdf2w/build.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="org.dita.pdf2w">
    <target name="dita2pdf2w.init">
        <property location="${dita.plugin.org.dita.pdf2w.dir}/cfg" name="customization.dir"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="dita2pdf2w.init, dita2pdf2" name="dita2pdf2w"/>
</project>
```

This will work surely if you properly configure pdf2w/cfg directory.

Following files are one of simple customization examples:

[pdf2w/cfg/catalog.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">
   <!-- Custom XSL code entry.-->
   <uri name="cfg:fo/xsl/custom.xsl" uri="fo/xsl/custom.xsl"/>
</catalog>
```

[pdf2w/cfg/fo/xsl/custom.xsl]

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' task/cmd ')]" priority="1">
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="cmd">
            <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="color" select="'red'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="font-size" select="'2em'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="font-weight" select="'bold'"/>
            <xsl:if test="../@importance='optional'">
                <xsl:call-template name="getVariable">
                    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'Optional Step'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="../@importance='required'">
                <xsl:call-template name="getVariable">
                    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'Required Step'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[command-line in Windows]

`D:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.4>bin\dita -i docsrc/samples/sequence.ditamap -f pdf2w -o out`

[Result PDF]

[image: Sample PDF]

Comment: Thank You , but what about the ant file for generating output ? http://www.dita-ot.org/2.3/user-guide/creating-an-ant-build-script.html

Comment: I guess this is for Oxygen. I am not using oxygen. I need to create ant script too.

Comment: I followed your's and Radu's instructions and get into this point of errors:-BUILD FAILED
`C:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4\build.xml:45: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4\plugins\org.dita.pdf2\build.xml:140: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\dita-ot-2.4\plugins\org.dita.pdf2.fop\build_fop.xml:151: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.Metadata.mergeInto(Lorg/apache/xmlgraphics/xmp/Metadata;)`

Comment: @RohitGhosh This is tested via command-line not from oXygen at all. Your build result shows that you are facing another problem in your customization. Try above example and if it works, it is better to submit a new question.

Comment: Thank You Sir. I am posting a new question regarding this issue.

Comment: Sir , I can generate default ditamap pdf but , there is no changes which i had made in my plugin xslt. The output is default. Guess the dependency is of pdf2 plugin. I dont want dependency , want to run my own.

Comment: @RohitGhosh Originally your question belongs plug-in integration. If you cannot get expected result by your customization, it is a problem of your customization codes. Please submit new question showing your minimum customization code and desired output.